# Changed position in department but others act as if I'm still doing my old job

Tags: career-development, job-change, colleagues

After a key employee left, our department reorganized and I ended up in a different position within the department. Despite a company-wide announcement, some people continue to act as if I'm still doing my old job. How do I get them to recognize that I'm doing something new and stop expecting me to essentially do both jobs?

Comment: Please define "continue to act" -- do they send you requests for meetings or specific work requests under the assumption that you are the correct person to attend the meeting/do the work? Or something else?

Comment: Can't you just redirect them?  Eventually they will stop asking you and go to the responsible person.

Comment: This seems to be relatively common; I'm in the same boat because my promotion left my old duty short-staffed. It's probably temporary.

Answer (score 13):

If they are your superior, then ask them for a list of your new job duties to make sure that you are all on the same page.

Anyone else, tell them, "Actually, since I transferred to my new role, I'm not supposed to be doing that any longer.  Please see Dave at extension 321 for that.  I'll let him know to expect you."

Polite, helpful, and direct.  Can't beat it.

Comment: Agreed, keep it short and simple. I would add that if the person has a problem with this, direct them to your manager so someone with more authority than you can back you up. They can direct them to the person they need to be dealing with now, and they're now made aware that people are still trying to contact you related to tasks you're no longer responsible for. This both "covers your ass", and puts the responsibility of notifying others of the change in positions back on them (where it should be).